# Writeln from kuberntes pod to windows directory

Tags: spring, kubernetes, deployment

I have a Spring Boot code that writes in a file currently I am writing to a file located in the container's home directory, and then manually copying it to a Windows directory. However, this is not an ideal solution sinc the container ID can changes some times. I asked ChatGPT for a solution, and he suggested using a hostpath solution. he provided this code to add it to my deployment file? I want to directly write in windows directory file .

```
 volumeMounts:
            - name: data-volume
              mountPath: /data
      volumes:
        - name: data-volume
          hostPath:
            path: "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/fold"
            type: Directory
```

but after I added this the container fail to run and I get this error

```
Warning FailedMount 4s (x7 over 36s) kubelet MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "data-volume" : hostPath type check failed: C:/Users/HP/Desktop/fold is not a directory
```

also he provided me PersistentVolume file to be honset I dont know what this is for Im new to this kubernetes world

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  hostPath:
    path: C:/Users/HP/Desktop/fold

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

How can I achieve this (Im using Kubernetes using Docker desktop)?

Comment: Ensure "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/fold" is a directory in your desktop.  Kubelet is complaining on the same.  More details about hostpath and how it works can referred in following link https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath